# How to store standard error in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, variables, stderr

Let's say I have a script like the following:

useless.sh

```
echo "This Is Error" 1>&2
echo "This Is Output"
```

And I have another shell script:

alsoUseless.sh

```
./useless.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/'
```

I want to capture "This Is Error", or any other stderr from useless.sh, into a variable. 
Let's call it ERROR.

Notice that I am using stdout for something. I want to continue using stdout, so redirecting stderr into stdout is not helpful, in this case.

So, basically, I want to do

```
./useless.sh 2> $ERROR | ...
```

but that obviously doesn't work.

I also know that I could do

```
./useless.sh 2> /tmp/Error
ERROR=`cat /tmp/Error`
```

but that's ugly and unnecessary.

Unfortunately, if no answers turn up here that's what I'm going to have to do.

I'm hoping there's another way.

Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: What exactly to want to use stdout for? Do you simply want to view it on the console? Or are you capturing/redirecting it's output? If it's just to the console you redirect stdout to console and stderr to stdout to capture it: `ERROR=$(./useless.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/' 2>&1 1>/dev/ttyX)`

Comment: For the more mundane scenario where you want to capture both stdout and stderr, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115949/output-not-captured-in-bash-variable?noredirect=1

Comment: @psycotica0, check this one it might help 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108786/5372008

Answer (score 135, accepted):

It would be neater to capture the error file thus:

```
ERROR=$(</tmp/Error)
```

The shell recognizes this and doesn't have to run '`cat`' to get the data.

The bigger question is hard.  I don't think there's an easy way to do it.  You'd have to build the entire pipeline into the sub-shell, eventually sending its final standard output to a file, so that you can redirect the errors to standard output.

```
ERROR=$( { ./useless.sh | sed s/Output/Useless/ > outfile; } 2>&1 )
```

Note that the semi-colon is needed (in classic shells - Bourne, Korn - for sure; probably in Bash too).  The '`{}`' does I/O redirection over the enclosed commands.  As written, it would capture errors from `sed` too.

> **WARNING:** Formally untested code - use at own risk.

Comment: I had hoped that there'd be some really crazy trick I didn't know, but it looks like this is it.
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need the standard output, you can redirect it to `/dev/null` instead of `outfile` (If you're like me, you found this question via Google, and don't have the same requirements as the OP)

Comment: For an answer without temporary files, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52587939/5353461).

Comment: [Here](http://sebthom.de/158-bash-capturing-stderr-variable/) is a way to do it without redirecting it to files; it plays with swapping `stdout` and `stderr` forth and back. But _beware_, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script/52587939#52587939) is said: _In bash, it would be better not to assume that file descriptor 3 is unused"_.

Answer (score 108):

Redirected stderr to stdout, stdout to /dev/null, and then use the backticks or `$()` to capture the redirected stderr:

```
ERROR=$(./useless.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Comment: This is the reason I included the pipe in my example.
I still want the standard output, and I want it to do other things, go other places.

Comment: For commands that send output only to stderr, the simple way to capture it is, for example
`PY_VERSION="$(python --version 2>&1)"`

Answer (score 83):

### alsoUseless.sh

This will allow you to pipe the output of your `useless.sh` script through a command such as `sed` and save the `stderr` in a variable named `error`. The result of the pipe is sent to `stdout` for display or to be piped into another command.

It sets up a couple of extra file descriptors to manage the redirections needed in order to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1 4>&2 #set up extra file descriptors

error=$( { ./useless.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/' 2>&4 1>&3; } 2>&1 )

echo "The message is \"${error}.\""

exec 3>&- 4>&- # release the extra file descriptors
```

Comment: It is good technique to use 'exec' to set and close file descriptors.  The close isn't really needed if the script exits immediately afterwards.

Comment: How would I capture both `stderr` and `stdout` in variables?

Comment: Excellent. This helps me implement a `dry_run` function that can reliably choose between echoing its arguments and running them, regardless of whether the command being dry-ran is being piped to some other file.

Comment: This is easy to achieve in Zsh, but this technique won't work in Bash.

stdout=$(echo good; echo bad >&2) 2>&1 | read stderr; echo "stdout=>$stdout"; echo "stderr=>$stderr"

stdout=>good

stderr=>bad

Comment: @t00bs: `read` doesn't accept input from a pipe. You can use other techniques to achieve what you're trying to demonstrate.

Comment: Could be simpler, with: error=$( ./useless.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/' 2>&1 1>&3 )

Comment: @Gingi I can't see a simple way to do both at once—you can add a separate call to the program as `OUT=$( my_cmd | tee >(cat - >&3) )` where `my_cmd` is the error-generating program (but this requires running the STDOUT/STDERR-generating program twice) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12451419/2668831). I couldn't see any mention of how to `tee` redirect STDERR to variable in the same command. A more advanced solution is to ["decorate the stdout and stderr differently and remove the decoration upon reading:"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430182/89254) (adds trailing newlines)

Answer (score 33):

There are a lot of duplicates for this question, many of which have a slightly simpler usage scenario where you don't want to capture stderr *and* stdout *and* the exit code all at the same time.

```
if result=$(useless.sh 2>&1); then
    stdout=$result
else
    rc=$?
    stderr=$result
fi
```

works for the common scenario where you expect either proper output in the case of success, or a diagnostic message on stderr in the case of failure.

Note that the shell's control statements already examine `$?` under the hood; so anything which looks like

```
cmd
if [ $? -eq 0 ], then ...
```

is just a clumsy, unidiomatic way of saying

```
if cmd; then ...
```

Answer (score 20):

For the benefit of the reader, this recipe here

- can be re-used as oneliner to catch stderr into a variable
- still gives access to the return code of the command
- Sacrifices a temporary file descriptor 3 (which can be changed by you of course)
- And does not expose this temporary file descriptors to the inner command

If you want to catch `stderr` of some `command` into `var` you can do

```
{ var="$( { command; } 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- )"; } 3>&1;
```

Afterwards you have it all:

```
echo "command gives $? and stderr '$var'";
```

If `command` is simple (not something like `a | b`) you can leave the inner `{}` away:

```
{ var="$(command 2>&1 1>&3 3>&-)"; } 3>&1;
```

Wrapped into an easy reusable `bash`-function (probably needs version 3 and above for `local -n`):

```
: catch-stderr var cmd [args..]
catch-stderr() { local -n v="$1"; shift && { v="$("$@" 2>&1 1>&3 3>&-)"; } 3>&1; }
```

Explained:

- `local -n` aliases "$1" (which is the variable for `catch-stderr`)
- `3>&1` uses file descriptor 3 to save there stdout points
- `{ command; }` (or "$@") then executes the command within the output capturing `$(..)`
- Please note that the exact order is important here (doing it the wrong way shuffles the file descriptors wrongly):

  - `2>&1` redirects `stderr` to the output capturing `$(..)`
  - `1>&3` redirects `stdout` away from the output capturing `$(..)` back to the "outer" `stdout` which was saved in file descriptor 3.  Note that `stderr` still refers to where FD 1 pointed before:  To the output capturing `$(..)`
  - `3>&-` then closes the file descriptor 3 as it is no more needed, such that `command` does not suddenly has some unknown open file descriptor showing up.  Note that the outer shell still has FD 3 open, but `command` will not see it.
  - The latter is important, because some programs like `lvm` complain about unexpected file descriptors.  And `lvm` complains to `stderr` - just what we are going to capture!

You can catch any other file descriptor with this recipe, if you adapt accordingly.  Except file descriptor 1 of course (here the redirection logic would be wrong, but for file descriptor 1 you can just use `var=$(command)` as usual).

Note that this sacrifices file descriptor 3.  If you happen to need that file descriptor, feel free to change the number.  But be aware, that some shells (from the 1980s) might understand `99>&1` as argument `9` followed by `9>&1` (this is no problem for `bash`).

Also note that it is not particluar easy to make this FD 3 configurable through a variable.  This makes things very unreadable:

```
: catch-var-from-fd-by-fd variable fd-to-catch fd-to-sacrifice command [args..]
catch-var-from-fd-by-fd()
{
local -n v="$1";
local fd1="$2" fd2="$3";
shift 3 || return;

eval exec "$fd2>&1";
v="$(eval '"$@"' "$fd1>&1" "1>&$fd2" "$fd2>&-")";
eval exec "$fd2>&-";
}
```

> **Security note:** The first 3 arguments to `catch-var-from-fd-by-fd` must not be taken from a 3rd party.  Always give them explicitly in a "static" fashion.
>
> So no-no-no `catch-var-from-fd-by-fd $var $fda $fdb $command`, never do this!
>
> If you happen to pass in a variable variable name, at least do it as follows:
>   `local -n var="$var"; catch-var-from-fd-by-fd var 3 5 $command`
>
> This still will not protect you against every exploit, but at least helps to detect and avoid common scripting errors.

Notes:

- `catch-var-from-fd-by-fd var 2 3 cmd..` is the same as `catch-stderr var cmd..`
- `shift || return` is just some way to prevent ugly errors in case you forget to give the correct number of arguments.  Perhaps terminating the shell would be another way (but this makes it hard to test from commandline).
- The routine was written such, that it is more easy to understand.  One can rewrite the function such that it does not need `exec`, but then it gets really ugly.
- This routine can be rewritten for non-`bash` as well such that there is no need for `local -n`.  However then you cannot use local variables and it gets extremely ugly!
- Also note that the `eval`s are used in a safe fashion.  Usually `eval` is considerered dangerous.  However in this case it is no more evil than using `"$@"` (to execute arbitrary commands).  However please be sure to use the exact and correct quoting as shown here (else it becomes **very very dangerous**).

Comment: I don't think it gives access to the return code of the command

Comment: I don't see the local -n option in the bash 3.2 nor 4.2 man pages, just in the 5.2 man page.

Answer (score 8):

```
# command receives its input from stdin.
# command sends its output to stdout.
exec 3>&1
stderr="$(command </dev/stdin 2>&1 1>&3)"
exitcode="${?}"
echo "STDERR: $stderr"
exit ${exitcode}
```

Comment: `command` is a bad choice here, inasmuch as there's actually a builtin by that name. Might make it `yourCommand` or such, to be more explicit.

Comment: exitcode is always zero

Comment: is it really necessary to do anything with /dev/stdin?  Since FD=0 is not touched anywhere n your command im not sure what is gained

Answer (score 6):

### POSIX

STDERR can be captured with some redirection magic:

```
$ { error=$( { { ls -ld /XXXX /bin | tr o Z ; } 1>&3 ; } 2>&1); } 3>&1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rZZt rZZt 7 Aug 22 15:44 /bin -> usr/bin/

$ echo $error
ls: cannot access '/XXXX': No such file or directory
```

Note that piping of STDOUT of the command (here `ls`) is done inside the innermost `{` `}`. If you're executing a simple command (eg, not a pipe), you could remove these inner braces.

You can't pipe outside the command as piping makes a subshell in `bash` and `zsh`, and the assignment to the variable in the subshell wouldn't be available to the current shell.

### bash

In `bash`, it would be better not to assume that file descriptor 3 is unused:

```
{ error=$( { { ls -ld /XXXX /bin | tr o Z ; } 1>&$tmp ; } 2>&1); } {tmp}>&1; 
exec {tmp}>&-  # With this syntax the FD stays open
```

Note that this doesn't work in `zsh`.

---

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963857/5353461) for the general idea.

Comment: can u explain this line with details? did not understood 1>&$tmp ;
{ error=$( { { ls -ld /XXXX /bin | tr o Z ; } 1>&$tmp ; } 2>&1); } {tmp}>&1;

Comment: @ThiagoConrado I assume `tmp` in that case is just a variable that stores a file descriptor that you know is unused. For example, if `tmp=3` then `1>&$tmp` would become `1>&3` and the command would be the same as explained previously (it would store `stdout` (`1`) in the file descriptor `3`, than `stderr` (`2`) would go to `stdout` and be stored in the `error` variable, and finally the content streamed to the file descriptor `3` goes back to the file descriptor `1`, that is, `stdout`, because of `{tmp}>&1` that turns into `3>&1`, if I understood correctly).

Answer (score 6):

### A simple solution

```
{ ERROR=$(./useless.sh 2>&1 1>&$out); } {out}>&1
echo "-"
echo $ERROR
```

Will produce:

```
This Is Output
-
This Is Error
```

Comment: I like this. I tweaked it to this: OUTPUT=$({ ERROR=$(~/code/sh/x.sh  2>&1 1>&$TMP_FD); } {TMP_FD}>&1)
 this also allows the status to be seen via $?

Comment: @kdubs I've tried your solution but the ERROR is always empty. Even if the command failed. Have I missed something?
`$ STDOUT="$({ STDERR="$(ls -l /tmp/non-existing-file 2>&1 1>&$out)"; } {out}>&1)"; echo "stdout = [$STDOUT], stderr = [$STDERR]";
stdout = [], stderr = []`

Have I missed something?

Comment: @kdubs I think to make it work in case of the error you have to swap 2>&1 and 1>&TMP_FD

So it looks so:
`STDOUT="$({ STDERR="$(ls -l /tmp/non-existing-file 1>&$out 2>&1)"; } {out}>&1)"; echo "stdout = [$STDOUT], stderr = [$STDERR]";`

Comment: mine is messed up. I got mislead, because the variables were set from a previous attempt. your ordering appears to write only to STDOUT

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to capture `stderr`, `stdout` and `exitcode` if that is your intention you can use this code:

```sh
## Capture error when 'some_command() is executed
some_command_with_err() {
    echo 'this is the stdout'
    echo 'this is the stderr' >&2
    exit 1
}

run_command() {
    {
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' stderr;
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' stdout;
        IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' stdexit;
    } < <((printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(some_command_with_err)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1)
    stdexit=${stdexit:-0};
}

echo 'Run command:'
if ! run_command; then
    ## Show the values
    typeset -p stdout stderr stdexit
else
    typeset -p stdout stderr stdexit
fi
```

This scripts capture the `stderr`, `stdout` as well as the `exitcode`.

#### But Teo how it works?

First, we capture the `stdout` as well as the `exitcode` using `printf '\0%s\0%d\0'`. They are separated by the `\0` aka **'null byte'**.

After that, we redirect the `printf` to `stderr` by doing: `1>&2` and then we redirect all back to `stdout` using `2>&1`. Therefore, the `stdout` will look like:

```sh
"<stderr>\0<stdout>\0<exitcode>\0"
```

Enclosing the `printf` command in `<( ... )` performs [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). Process substitution allows a process’s input or output to be referred to using a filename. This means `<( ... )` will pipe the `stdout` of `(printf '\0%s\0%d\0' "$(some_command_with_err)" "${?}" 1>&2) 2>&1`into the `stdin` of the [command group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) using the first `<`.

Then, we can capture the piped `stdout` from the `stdin` of the command group with `read`. This command reads a line from the file descriptor `stdin` and split it into fields. Only the characters found in `$IFS` are recognized as word delimiters. `$IFS` or [Internal Field Separator](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS) is a variable that determines how Bash recognizes fields, or word boundaries, when it interprets character strings. `$IFS` defaults to whitespace (space, tab, and newline), but may be changed, for example, to parse a comma-separated data file. Note that `$*` uses the first character held in $IFS.

```sh
## Shows whitespace as a single space, ^I(horizontal tab), and newline, and display "$" at end-of-line.
echo "$IFS" | cat -vte
# Output:
# ^I$
# $

## Reads commands from string and assign any arguments to pos params
bash -c 'set w x y z; IFS=":-;"; echo "$*"'
# Output:
# w:x:y:z

for l in $(printf %b 'a b\nc'); do echo "$l"; done
# Output: 
# a
# b
# c

IFS=$'\n'; for l in $(printf %b 'a b\nc'); do echo "$l"; done
# Output: 
# a b
# c
```

That is why we defined `IFS=$'\n'` (newline) as delimiter.
Our script uses `read -r -d ''`, where `read -r` does not allow backslashes to escape any characters, and `-d ''` continues until the first character `''` is read, rather than newline.

Finally, replace `some_command_with_err` with your script file and you can capture and handle the `stderr`, `stdout` as well as the `exitcode` as your will.

Comment: Does it work with more than 512 bytes ?

Answer (score 4):

Iterating a bit on [Tom Hale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52587939/7275674), I've found it possible to wrap the redirection yoga into a function for easier reuse.  For example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

capture () {
    { captured=$( { { "$@" ; } 1>&3 ; } 2>&1); } 3>&1
}

# Example usage; capturing dialog's output without resorting to temp files
# was what motivated me to search for this particular SO question
capture dialog --menu "Pick one!" 0 0 0 \
        "FOO" "Foo" \
        "BAR" "Bar" \
        "BAZ" "Baz"
choice=$captured

clear; echo $choice
```

It's almost certainly possible to simplify this further.  Haven't tested especially-thoroughly, but it does appear to work with both bash and ksh.

---

**EDIT:** an alternative version of the `capture` function which stores the captured STDERR output into a user-specified variable (instead of relying on a global `$captured`), taking inspiration from [Léa Gris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936303/7275674) while preserving the `ksh` (and `zsh`) compatibility of the above implementation:

```sh
capture () {
    if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: capture varname command [arg ...]"
        return 1
    fi
    typeset var captured; captured="$1"; shift
    { read $captured <<<$( { { "$@" ; } 1>&3 ; } 2>&1); } 3>&1
}
```

And usage:

```sh
capture choice dialog --menu "Pick one!" 0 0 0 \
        "FOO" "Foo" \
        "BAR" "Bar" \
        "BAZ" "Baz"

clear; echo $choice
```

Comment: It looks like the $? value of the command executed is lost in the process. It is possible to preserve it ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it :

```
#
# $1 - name of the (global) variable where the contents of stderr will be stored
# $2 - command to be executed
#
captureStderr()
{
    local tmpFile=$(mktemp)

    $2 2> $tmpFile

    eval "$1=$(< $tmpFile)"

    rm $tmpFile
}
```

Usage example :

```
captureStderr err "./useless.sh"

echo -$err-
```

It *does* use a temporary file. But at least the ugly stuff is wrapped in a function.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Little doubt on my side. In French, colon is usually preceded by a space. I mistakenly apply this same rule with *english* answers. After checking [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)), I know I won't make this mistake again.

Comment: @Stephan cheers, this has also been discussed [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67394/spaces-around-a-colon). :)

Comment: There are safer ways to do this than using `eval`. For instance, `printf -v "$1" '%s' "$(<tmpFile)"` doesn't risk running arbitrary code if your `TMPDIR` variable has been set to a malicious value (or your destination variable name contains such a value).

Comment: Similarly, `rm -- "$tmpFile"` is more robust than `rm $tmpFile`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem to which I hoped there was an elegant solution.  Sadly, I end up with a solution similar to Mr. Leffler, but I'll add that you can call useless from inside a Bash function for improved readability:

```
#!/bin/bash

function useless {
    /tmp/useless.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/'
}

ERROR=$(useless)
echo $ERROR
```

All other kind of output redirection must be backed by a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me come up with a similar solution for my own purposes:

```
MESSAGE=`{ echo $ERROR_MESSAGE | format_logs.py --level=ERROR; } 2>&1`
```

Then as long as our MESSAGE is not an empty string, we pass it on to other stuff.  This will let us know if our format_logs.py failed with some kind of python exception.

Answer (score 1):

In zsh:

```
{ . ./useless.sh > /dev/tty } 2>&1 | read ERROR
$ echo $ERROR
( your message )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Capture AND Print stderr**

```
ERROR=$( ./useless.sh 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee /dev/fd/2 )
```

**Breakdown**

You can use `$()` to capture stdout, but you want to capture stderr instead.  So you swap stdout and stderr.  Using fd 3 as the temporary storage in the standard swap algorithm.

If you want to capture AND print use `tee` to make a duplicate.  In this case the output of `tee` will be captured by `$()` rather than go to the console, but stderr(of `tee`) will still go to the console so we use that as the second output for `tee` via the special file `/dev/fd/2` since `tee` expects a file path rather than a fd number.

NOTE: That is an awful lot of redirections in a single line and the order matters.  `$()` is grabbing the stdout of `tee` at the end of the pipeline and the pipeline itself routes stdout of `./useless.sh` to the stdin of `tee` AFTER we swapped stdin and stdout for `./useless.sh`.

**Using stdout of ./useless.sh**

The OP said he still wanted to use (not just print) stdout, like `./useless.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/'`.

No problem just do it BEFORE swapping stdout and stderr.  I recommend moving it into a function or file (also-useless.sh) and calling that in place of ./useless.sh in the line above.

However, if you want to CAPTURE stdout AND stderr, then I think you have to fall back on temporary files because `$()` will only do one at a time and it makes a subshell from which you cannot return variables.

Answer (score 1):

Improving on [YellowApple's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829273/7939871):

This is a Bash function to capture stderr into any variable

`stderr_capture_example.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Capture stderr from a command to a variable while maintaining stdout
# @Args:
# $1: The variable name to store the stderr output
# $2: Vararg command and arguments
# @Return:
# The Command's Returnn-Code or 2 if missing arguments
function capture_stderr {
  [ $# -lt 2 ] && return 2
  local stderr="$1"
  shift
  {
    printf -v "$stderr" '%s' "$({ "$@" 1>&3; } 2>&1)"
  } 3>&1
}

# Testing with a call to erroring ls
LANG=C capture_stderr my_stderr ls "$0" ''

printf '\nmy_stderr contains:\n%s' "$my_stderr"
```

Testing:

```sh
bash stderr_capture_example.sh
```

Output:

```
 stderr_capture_example.sh

my_stderr contains:
ls: cannot access '': No such file or directory
```

This function can be used to capture the returned choice of a `dialog` command.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use `find` command

```
find / -maxdepth 2 -iname 'tmp' -type d
```

as non superuser for the demo. It should complain 'Permission denied' when acessing `/` dir.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "terminal:"
{ err="$(find / -maxdepth 2 -iname 'tmp' -type d 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- | tee /dev/stderr)"; } 3>&1 | tee /dev/fd/4 2>&1; out=$(cat /dev/fd/4)
echo "stdout:" && echo "$out"
echo "stderr:" && echo "$err"
```

that gives output:

```
terminal:
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
/tmp
/var/tmp
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
stdout:
/tmp
/var/tmp
stderr:
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
```

The `terminal` output has also `/dev/stderr` content the same way as if you were running that find command without any script. `$out` has `/dev/stdout` and `$err` has `/dev/stderr` content.

use:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "terminal:"
{ err="$(find / -maxdepth 2 -iname 'tmp' -type d 2>&1 1>&3 3>&-)"; } 3>&1 | tee /dev/fd/4; out=$(cat /dev/fd/4)
echo "stdout:" && echo "$out"
echo "stderr:" && echo "$err"
```

if you don't want to see `/dev/stderr` in the terminal output.

```
terminal:
/tmp
/var/tmp
stdout:
/tmp
/var/tmp
stderr:
find: ‘/root’: Permission denied
find: ‘/lost+found’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass the use of a temporary file you may be able to use process substitution. I haven't quite gotten it to work yet. This was my first attempt:

```
$ .useless.sh 2> >( ERROR=$(<) )
-bash: command substitution: line 42: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
-bash: command substitution: line 42: `<)'
```

Then I tried

```
$ ./useless.sh 2> >( ERROR=$( cat <() )  )
This Is Output
$ echo $ERROR   # $ERROR is empty
```

However

```
$ ./useless.sh 2> >( cat <() > asdf.txt )
This Is Output
$ cat asdf.txt
This Is Error
```

So the process substitution is doing *generally* the right thing... unfortunately, whenever I wrap STDIN inside `>( )` with something in `$()` in an attempt to capture that to a variable, I lose the contents of `$()`. I think that this is because `$()` launches a sub process which no longer has access to the file descriptor in /dev/fd which is owned by the parent process.

Process substitution has bought me the ability to work with a data stream which is no longer in STDERR, unfortunately I don't seem to be able to manipulate it the way that I want.

Comment: If you did `./useless.sh 2> >( ERROR=$( cat <() ); echo "$ERROR" )` then you would see output of `ERROR`. The trouble is that the process substitution is run in a sub-shell, so the value set in the sub-shell doesn't affect the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ b=$( ( a=$( (echo stdout;echo stderr >&2) ) ) 2>&1 )
$ echo "a=>$a b=>$b"
a=>stdout b=>stderr
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea, but on Mac OSX 10.8.5, it prints `a=> b=>stderr`

Comment: I agree with @HeathBorders; this does not produce the output shown. The trouble here is that `a` is evaluated and assigned in a sub-shell, and the assignment in the sub-shell does not affect the parent shell.  (Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as well as Mac OS X 10.10.1.)

Comment: The same in Windows GitBash. So, it doesn't work. (`GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)`)

Comment: Does not work on `SLE 11.4` either and produces the effect described by @JonathanLeffler

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

For **error proofing** your commands:

```
execute [INVOKING-FUNCTION] [COMMAND]
```

---

```
execute () {
    function="${1}"
    command="${2}"
    error=$(eval "${command}" 2>&1 >"/dev/null")

    if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "${function}: ${error}"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

---

**Inspired** in Lean manufacturing:

- [Make errors impossible by design](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/poka-y10.jpg)
- [Make steps the smallest](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/kaizen10.png)
- [Finish items one by one](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/one_pi10.png)
- [Make it obvious to anyone](https://i62.servimg.com/u/f62/16/19/87/90/visual10.png)

Comment: The idiomatic solution is toeput the assignment inside the `if`. Let me post a separate solution.