# Bash how do you capture stderr to a variable?

Tags: bash, stderr

Bash how do you capture stderr to a variable?

I would like to do something like this inside of my bash script

```
sh -c path/myExcecutable-bin 2>&1 =MYVARIABLE
```

How do you send stderror output to a variable ?

Comment: This StackOverflow [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script) should answer your question.

Comment: See one of the many related threads, and [several solutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

To save both `stdout` *and* `stderr` to a variable:

```
MYVARIABLE="$(path/myExcecutable-bin 2>&1)"
```

Note that this interleaves stdout and stderr into the same variable.

To save *just* `stderr` to a variable:

```
MYVARIABLE="$(path/myExcecutable-bin 2>&1 > /dev/null)"
```

Comment: I just want to note that you will save both stderr and stdout to the variable. When you need only `stderr` use `2>&1 >/dev/null`

Comment: @IgorChubin Good point.  I was basing my original answer on what it looked like the OP wanted to do, but that isn't necessarily what they actually wanted.  See my changes.

Comment: Pretty sure that should be "`stdout` _and_ `stderr`", no?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. "`stdout` _and_ `stderr`" is literally the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. There was an edit. Yeah, that should have been stdout, not stdin. :)