# How to write shell output by string to file

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, console, sh

I have some shell process, i need to catch errors that comes with it by string from specific line. So, i'm doing this:

```
OUTPUT="$(npm run generate_post)"
echo ${OUTPUT} | grep "_currentUrl" * > error.log
```

but i don't have any results, can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you have `*` after `grep` while reading input from a pipe? It should just be `echo "${OUTPUT}" | grep "_currentUrl" > error.log` or just `npm run generate_post | grep "_currentUrl" > error.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your statement doesn't make sense:

```
 echo ${OUTPUT} | grep "_currentUrl" *
```

The asterisk expands to the files in the working directory, and grep is searching the pattern there, ignoring what comes from stdin. I have no idea what you intended with `*`.

Then, you didn't specify whether you need the full output of npm later on. Assuming that you don't, you can write

```
npm run generate_post | grep _currentUrl
```

Of course it might be wise to follow the advice by Triptych to capture stderr too, but this is a different story.

If you do need the full output of npm, consider putting it into a file instead of a variable - of course this depends on how you are going to use it later, so this is just one of several options:

```
npm run generate_post | tee npm_output.txt | grep _currentUrl
```

Comment: Hey, it's working fine, but how can i print the line that contains this phrase "_currentUrl", right now i have all data from npm ... THX

Comment: ???? The grep command ensures that the STDOUT only lines containing the string _currentUrl. If you see additional information, this is most likely not STDOUT, but STDERR, as has been repeatedly pointed out in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna guess that your `npm run generate_post` is outputting errors on STDERR, but you're capture STDOUT. Try this:

```
OUTPUT="$(npm run generate_post 2>&1)"
echo ${OUTPUT} | grep "_currentUrl" * > error.log
```

Note that the above would capture *both* STDERR and STDOUT. More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087499/bash-how-do-you-capture-stderr-to-a-variable).

Comment: this is what i have in my error.log file => `generate_post.sh:echo ${OUTPUT} | grep "_currentUrl" * > error.log` :(