# How I can catch output of gitlab-runner in bash

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci-runner

Why when I write into terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
out=`gitlab-runner list`
echo "list: ${out}"
```

`out` variable is still empty and output of the command always display in terminal? [Install Gitlab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html)

How I can catch this output?

Comment: What's the output you're getting? A list and then a line with `list:` afterwards?

Comment: Command output first. Then `list: `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gitlab-runner list outputs the list on stderr, thus you would not catch it as output to stdout.

see [Bash how do you capture stderr to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087499/bash-how-do-you-capture-stderr-to-a-variable)

and change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
out="$(gitlab-runner list 2>&1)"
echo "list: ${out}"
```