# ssh result of remote command

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I need the return code of the command that is executed over a remote ssh.

```
result=$(ssh $TARGET_USER@$TARGET_SERVER \
'cp /tmp/test1.txt \
/tmp1/test2.txt')
```

when the above command is unsuccessful

I want to perform some alerting action.

But the output of the result variable seems to be always null

any ideas how do i make use of the result variable

When i execute the above command i get this

cp: cannot create regular file ‘/tmp1/test2.txt’: No such file or directory

Comment: Is it always null, even when it succeeds? If this is correct, perhaps you will need to capture `stderr` into the variable instead of `stdout`...

Comment: `result=$(ssh $TARGET_USER@$TARGET_SERVER 'cp /tmp/test1.txt /tmp1/test2.txt >/dev/null ; printf $?')`?

Comment: @SebasSBM yes its always null no matter what if it succeeds or fails

Comment: Wow Biffen I will try that tomorrow first thing that's a neat trick of adding $?.Wish you would make that as an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this is worth giving it a try:

```
result=$(ssh $TARGET_USER@$TARGET_SERVER \
'cp /tmp/test1.txt \
/tmp1/test2.txt 2>&1 > /dev/null')
```

[This answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087523/3692177) explained how to capture `stderr` into a variable. I just applied it to your command (I considered `stdout` was unnecessary for this)

If it works as expected, the "no such file or directory" error you mentioned will be captured into this variable. Thus, you would have a differentiable value that might allow your code "know" if command was successful or not (`stderr` would be empty if command was successfull, in theory)

Answer (score 2):

Just check the **exit code**:

```
result=$(ssh $TARGET_USER@$TARGET_SERVER 'cp /tmp/test1.txt /tmp1/test2.txt' 2>/dev/null)

[[ $? -ne 0 ]] && your_error_flow
```

From **man ssh**:

> ```
>  ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command or with 255 if an error
>  occurred.
> ```