# Bash, assigning command output to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to automate the installation of nginx on multiple servers, and I have a shell script. It runs a version check if nginx is already installed and its version.

Trying to assign `TMP=$(nginx -v)`, and instead of storing it in the variable it prints the results to console. `printf "$TMP"` prints an empty string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does `nginx -v` outputs to STDOUT or to STDERR?

Comment: @Rob can u link he duplicate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your command does not print to STDOUT but to STDERR.

Using:

```sh
TMP=$(nginx -v 2>&1)
```

will solve your issue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087499/bash-how-do-you-capture-stderr-to-a-variable) for more details.

Comment: it actually outputs to STDOUT, nginx is installed so i assume there should be no error

Comment: I do not know which version do you have, but for me (`nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`) it is outputing to STDERR. Does the above not work for you?

Comment: oh, wow how to check if ti outputs to stderr for a future reference ?

Comment: You typically cannot tell by looking at the screen. A common way is to try to redirect STDERR and/or STDOUT to different files. But my favorite is to use: https://github.com/sickill/stderred and have STDERR colored in red :-)