# Assign output of command to variable in BASH

Tags: bash, nginx

I would like to assign output of a specific command to variable (`nginx -v`). My trouble can be seen at printscreen bellow, it still prints output to stdout.

Thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: The command `nginx -v` is most likely writing its output to `/dev/stderr`. You can just pick it up with `nginx -v 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
a=$(nginx -v 2>&1)
echo $a
```

[Bash how do you capture stderr to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087499/bash-how-do-you-capture-stderr-to-a-variable)

Comment: I had the same issue but the above command did not work for nginx