# In bash, how to redirect the stderr of a command inside the script to the stderr of the script itself?

Tags: bash, function, redirect, stderr

I have a bash script that has a print function, like this:

```
print(){
  [ $quiet == 1 ] && return
  type=$1; shift
  message="$*"; shift $#
  # shellcheck disable=SC2086
  if [ $type -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$message"
  else
    >&2 echo "$message"
  fi
}
```

In a nutshell it receives 2 parameters, the first is the type, if 1 it will print the message on the screen (stdout), else (in that case 2) it will print the message on the `stderr`. Also, I have a `quiet` var that says that if my program is called with `-q`, it will not print anything on the screen whether its `stdout` or `stderr` (the function returns).

The problem is that throughout  my program when I run commands, I run them more or less like below:

```
ip link add "${interface}" &&
  print 1 " interface ${interface} added successfuly." ||
  { print 2 "  interface ${interface} could not be added."; return 1; }
```

It works fine (success message is printed) if the command runs without error (meaning `$? == 0`) but if my `quiet` var is `1` and the command runs with error (meaning `$? != 0`) it will not print my message from the `print()` instruction (as expected), but it will print the error from the command itself, for example, `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.

Ideally, what I wanted was to not just run all my commands with `2> /dev/null` since the error messages can be important, but I would like to redirect them to my `print()` function with the type 2, so they would be printed on `stderr` only if my quiet var is `0`. As if I ran a program with `2> $(print 2 "RTNETLINK answers: File exists")` even though I know that this doesn't make since.

I thought about doing something like:

```
ip link add "${interface}" 2> /var/tmp/myprog.output || print 2 $(cat /var/tmp/myprog.output)
```

But 1) I would prefer not to use the filesystem for that and 2) there must be a more elegant way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could [capture the `stderr` of the command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087499/bash-how-do-you-capture-stderr-to-a-variable) and pass it to `print`.

`print 2 "$(ip link add '${interface}' 2>&1 > /dev/null)"`

Comment: But you are redirecting stdout and stderr to null and passing nothing to print(). No?

Comment: @Adriano_Pinaffo That should capture the `stderr` by redirecting it as `stdout` and direct the original `stdout` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: but in that case, I'm always passing the print parameter as 2... but that should only be two when there was an error with the program

Comment: In that case you would have to somehow capture both and check if the `stderr` is empty to decide what to print, but I don't think that's possible without running the command twice.

Comment: damn, maybe I will have to run the command and redirect stdout to a output.stdout file and stderr to output.stderr file and print whatever is not empty