# Bash Help >&3 into a variable?

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script for another question I'm asking.  Here's what I have:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/m.m.0001.u.cache.amazonaws.com/11211
echo -e "get CacheCleaner\nquit" >&3
cat <&3
```

It works, almost.  It returns this:

```
VALUE CacheCleaner 0 1
1
END
```

What I don't have the stills to do, is take the 1 on the middle line, and put it into a variable.

I tried editing the >&3, and I have some idea what that does, but I'm a bit lost.

---

Based on [How to store standard error in a variable in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script)

It looks like I can do:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/m.m.0001.u.cache.amazonaws.com/11211
echo -e "get CacheCleaner\nquit" >&3
CC=`cat <&3` 
echo $CC
```

This returns:

```
ENDE CacheCleaner 0 1
```

So not really what I need, but closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

`CC=$(cat <&3 | sed -n 2p)`

Answer (score 1):

```
dos2unix <&3 | sed -n 2p
```

The output appears to have `\r\n` line ending sequences. The dos2unix command converts `\r\n` to `\n` which is the UNIX style of line ending.

The sed command prints the second line of the output.

Comment: I saw you posted this in one of your edits: tr '\r' '\n' <&3 | sed -n 2p. Bingo

Comment: I see your point on the dos2unix though, which makes no real sense to me because both servers are running centos.  I just changed it to -n 3p and I'm pulling the third line.

Comment: @Beachhouse The HTTP protocol uses `\r\n` line endings even when the webserver is a Linux machine. I'm guessing Amazon's server speaks (or mimics) HTTP.

Comment: it does.  Memcache runs as an HTTP server.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
# instead of cat, do this
read a a a a result a <&3
echo $result
```