# Getting stderr from mbuffer to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables, stdout, stderr

When `mbuffer` finishes on the receiving side it prints the time and speed, which I would like to get into `$time` and `$speed`.

Trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/963857) answer

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2 #set up extra file descriptors
error=$( { mbuffer -v 0 -4 -s 128k -m 1G -I 8023 3>&1 4>&2 > /tank3/fs5/tst; } )
exec 3>&- 4>&- # release the extra file descriptors
echo "The message is \"${error}\""
```

Executing this and in another terminal

```
echo secret | mbuffer -4 -s 128k -m 1G -O localhost:8023
```

I get

```
# ./fff 

summary:  0.0 KiByte in  0.1 sec - average of  0.0 KiB/s
The message is ""
secret
```

where I was hoping to see the summary message between the `""`.

**Question**

I assume that the summary message must be printed to STDERR, as I pipe STDOUT to a file, and its content is correct.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have tried to apply the wrong solution. The one you referenced dealt with a somewhat more complicated problem. If your goal is to direct stdout to a file and capture stderr, this should do it (yes, it's counterintuitive to map stderr to stdout THEN stdout to a file, but that's how redirection works, you're sending stream 2 to where stream 1 points to at that moment, which is stdout)

```
error=$(mbuffer -v 0 -4 -s 128k -m 1G -I 8023 2>&1 > /tank3/fs5/tst)
echo "The message is \"${error}\""
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1
error=$({ mbuffer options >&3 ; } 2>&1)
exec 3>&-
echo "The message is \"${error}\"" >&2
```

This will pipe stdin through mbuffer to stdout, and write the processed stderr to stderr.