# Capture output from command into variable retaining new lines

Tags: bash, command

I have two scripts; `parentScript.sh` and `childScript.sh`.

I want to be able to call `childScript.sh` inside `parentScript.sh` and return the errors that occur within at any stage. i.e. an error found within `childScript.sh` looks like:

```
echo "ERROR: Feed file missing for $siteTag" >&2
```

I know how to [return the error `out` back towards the parent shell.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script)

But I have a feeling it is being tampered with, I can no longer `printf` the result to a nice looking variable. i.e.

```
error+="$( { ./childScript.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/' 2>&4 1>&3; } 2>&1 )"
error+="$( { ./childScript.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/' 2>&4 1>&3; } 2>&1 )"
```

Should essentially call the script twice, get errors from both scripts and store them in the variable `error` as I thought, which it does but it somehow gets rid of the lines both with the use of `echo "$error"` or `printf "$error"`.

Does anyone know a solution here to manage to grab error output from several commands but maintain the separate calls to `echo` within the `childScript.sh` commands?

Edit: Output should be..

```
ERROR: Feed file missing for (..)
ERROR: Feed file missing for (..)
ERROR: Feed file missing for (..)
```

But is instead

```
ERROR: Feed file missing for (..) ERROR: Feed file missing for (..) ERROR: Feed file missing for (..)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(..)` strips trailing line feeds. This is very useful most of the time, like in

```
echo "Welcome to $(hostname). Enjoy your stay."
```

However, in your case, it ruins it a bit. You can just add one back:

```
error+="$( { ./childScript.sh | sed 's/Output/Useless/' 2>&4 1>&3; } 2>&1 )"$'\n'
```

Comment: That doesn't solve it for multiple lines within one command, just multiple commands over multiple lines. :( Edit: Hang on... trying something.

Comment: @insidesin Line feeds within a command are not stripped or modified. If you use `echo "$error" ` as you say (and not `echo $error` or otherwise missing quotes), it's fine

Comment: Ugh. I think I know what was happening. When I migrated over to another script from my test one, I brought my changes with me and then proceeded to test on real world examples... ended up testing with more command calls than error echos, so thought it when I couldn't get back to one line per error, I was having issues.

I think in the end it's a case of trying to fix all at once, somehow breaking one part fixing another, etc. Thank you. :)