# Strange behaviour of command substitution in bash

Tags: bash

Command substitution:

```
var=$(cat /some/file.txt)
```

assigns output of cat command to var variable (without printing cat command output to console). Next I can print value of var variable:

```
echo "$var"
```

But

```
var=$(java -version)
```

or

```
var=$(fish -v)
```

will immediately print output of the command to console (even without echo command). Why?

Why var variable has no value now?

How can I assign output of the command (e.g. java -version) to variable?

Comment: You have a UUOC (unnecessary use of `cat`) in `var=$(cat /some/file.txt)`. No need to call `cat`, simply `var=$(</some/file.txt)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command substitutions only capture *stdout* output.

Presumably your commands output to *stderr*.

Using output redirection, you can capture stderr as well:

```
var=$(java -version 2>&1) # captures both stdout and stderr
```

Comment: I agree that version information should print to _stdout_, but some utilities do it their own way, unfortunately.

Comment: If your requirements are more complex than this, perhaps see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script