# Bash: Suppress standard output, capture error output

Tags: bash

So I'm running commands in a bash shell script, and I want to ONLY capture error output in a variable. Any standard output I want suppressed.

So far what I have definitely isn't working. So I'm trying to come up with a better idea, and struggling to find an answer.

Here's a code sample:

```
ERROR=$(svn switch "$NEW_URL" --accept postpone 1>/dev/null 2>&1) &
```

Looks like everything is getting suppressed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like that:

```
error=$({ echo "stdout"; echo "stderr" >&2; } 2>&1 >/dev/null)
echo "$error"
stderr
```

i.e. redirect `stderr->stdout` first and then redirect stdout to `/dev/null` to suppress `stdout`.

For your command it should be:

```
error=$(svn switch "$NEW_URL" --accept postpone 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

You also need to remove `&` to avoid pushing your command in background.