# Output not captured in bash variable

Tags: bash

I noticed that when trying to capture output of a command to a bash variable, some lines are not captured at all, although they are printed on the terminal when variable assigning is not done. One example is `ssh-keyscan`, when banner messages are enabled. Another example is access logs from a Python `SimpleHTTPServer`.

How are these getting printed on the terminal but not captured to a variable?

Comment: Because they are not sent to `stdout` but to `stderr`. See for example `ls laajalkdjlajfk` and `echo "hello"`. The former writes to `stderr`, while the latter to `stdout`.

Comment: That makes sense. Although, in the Python HTTP server's case, even when I've redirected 2>&1 to /dev/null the request logs are displayed in the terminal.

Comment: I see. You should give specific details on where and how you are using it to make us fully understand your question.

Comment: Standard output and standard error are not the only possible file descriptors. However, it is more likely that you wrote something like `2>&1 > /dev/null` instead of `> /dev/null 2>&1`, which is what directs both to `/dev/null`.

Comment: OUTPUT=$({ ERROR=$(cmd.sh  2>&1 1>&$TMP_FD); } {TMP_FD}>&1)
 this will capture both stderr and stdout in different variables, and let you see the status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably fedorqui have a reason in his comment...

And in this case you could redirect stderr to stdout using redirect option `2>&1`.
Like this :

```
toto=$( ls tioto 2>&1 )
echo $toto
ls: cannot access tioto: No such file or directory
```