# bash scripting - how to properly handle or trap errors for failed database connections

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a bash/shell script that has a `psql` database connection and the program fails with `psql: FATAL:  database "foo" does not exist`. This is fine because the program exits since it doesn't exist, but what I would like to do instead is trap or capture that `FATAL` message and perhaps echo or do something else.

Like if `message == "database "foo" does not exist`; then echo or run another function.

Here's my line of code that does db connection:

```
PGPASSWORD=$TARGET_PW "$PSQL" -h "$HOST2" -U masteruser -d "$database" -p 5439 << EOF 
        \a
        \t
        \o $LISTNEW
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = '$SCHEMAMAIN'
    AND table_name   = '$TBL'
    order by ordinal_position;
EOF
```

Can I get an example of how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edited version***

The best way to redirect a command’s `stderr` to a variable is

```
errMsg=$(some_command 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

so, for clarity, I would define a function around your original code

```
function my_psql () {
PGPASSWORD=$TARGET_PW "$PSQL" -h "$HOST2" -U masteruser -d "$database" -p 5439 << EOF 
        \a
        \t
        \o $LISTNEW
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = '$SCHEMAMAIN'
    AND table_name   = '$TBL'
   order by ordinal_position;
EOF
}
```

You are running your command in a script, and don’t want to redirect to `/dev/tty`. So:

```
# Save the script’s stdout in fd #10
exec 10>&1
# my_psql sends its stderr to the variable and its stdout to fd #10
errMsg=$(my_psql 2>&1 1>&10)
```

Now, you can do with the output of a non-failed command whatever you did before. You might also want to close fd #10 with `exec 10>&-` at a certain point.

Defining a function can also be useful to get rid of the `$PSQL` variable. Many of us follow the principle that *variables are for values, functions for commands* and have reasons not to store commands to be executed into variables, but this is irrelevant to your question and is more a matter of tastes...

See also [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002)
and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script).