# How to assign standard error stream output to a variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know that we can assign the output of a command in a script as below:

```
res=$(ls)    # assign the output of ls to res
```

Now I want to assign the error message to a variable:

```
res=$(XXXXXXX)
```

When I execute the script, which contains the code above, I get an error message on the terminal: command not found, whereas `res` is still empty.

Is it possible to assign `command not found` to `res` while there is nothing shown on the terminal?

Comment: Though this looks like a dupe, couldn't find one myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store standard error in a variable in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable-in-a-bash-script)

Comment: @PesaThe: I saw that but OP says `so redirecting stderr into stdout is not helpful, in this case.`

Comment: @Inian oops, I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/962268/6176817) and instantly thought OP tried to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done, just make sure to send `stderr(2)` stream to `stdout(1)` and suppress `stdout` to NULL(`/dev/null`)

```
res=$( non_existent_command 2>&1 >/dev/null )
```