# Record exit codes of all shell commands as they are executed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, exit-code

I would like to record the exit code of all shell commands from a specific TTY without additional syntax per command.

For example:

```
> source solution.sh # sets up this bash session to monitor exit codes
> ls
> ls f
ls: f: No such file or directory
> echo "hello world"
```

Some file would store exit codes:

```
0
1
0
```

Is this possible? If not, I am open to other ideas that might accomplish something similar.

My end goal is to collect data on all of my executed commands and their exit codes (kind of like `~/.bash_history` with exit codes appended)

Comment: I can't think of any straightforward way to do this. Also, if you have a command with subcommands, like an `if` block, do you want to save the exit codes of the subcommands and also the whole block?

Comment: What larger problem are you really trying to solve with this? Maybe there's a better way to achieve it.

Comment: I am trying to collect historical data on shell commands and their exit status.

Comment: Found some interesting ideas of here, but it has the unfortunate side effect of messing up the user's history: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158697/352331

Comment: Consider enabling process accounting.

Comment: Maybe a debug trap?

Comment: @Barmar - Process accounting may be what I'm looking for - I'll have to read up more on it before I can say for sure though. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @thatotherguy - could you elaborate with a small example maybe?

Comment: I believe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable/52587939#52587939) was provided previously to consider options

Comment: Can you use simply : `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo $? >> ~/exit-codes.log'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the numerous helpful comments, I have arrived at the following solutions to record exit codes of shell commands as they are executed:

1. Using trap debug:

   ```
    trap 'x=$?; echo "$x" >> ~/exit-codes.log' DEBUG
   ```
2. Using `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

   ```
    PROMPT_COMMAND='x=$?; echo "$x" >> ~/exit-codes.log; (exit $x)'
   ```

   Note that the `PROMPT_COMMAND` must exit with the exit code in order to preserve exit code history across shell commands.
3. [Process accounting](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/security-accounting.html) is a more principled solution for this, but it requires `sudo` access to enable.

The `solution.sh` I ended up using to log both exit codes *and* commands is the following:

```
trap 'previous_exit_code=$?; previous_command=$this_command; \
  this_command=$BASH_COMMAND; [ ! -z "$previous_command" ] && \ 
  echo \"$previous_command\", $previous_exit_code >> ~/exit-codes.log' DEBUG
```

Comment: You can write `PROMPT_COMMAND='x=$?; echo $x >> ~/exit-codes.log; (exit $x)'` to preserve the exit status.

Comment: @chepner - oh nice. Any other advantages to using PROMPT_COMMAND over trap DEBUG beyond conciseness?

Comment: It's not really any more concise; I just used shorter variable names :)

Comment: With `PROMPT_COMMAND='x=$?; echo x${x}x >> ~/exit.txt'`, I can do in my shell: `(exit 42)` followed by `echo $?` which prints 42.  That's without the `(exit $x)` in bash 4.4.19(1).

Comment: @ben-albrecht IIUC there isn't actually benefit over trap. Since if you don't use trap, you don't have access to $BASH_COMMAND(you will, but the value in it will be 'wrong'). So you can use say 'history 1', but then if press enter several times with empty input, you will log last command multiple times... I'll try to add my updated solution, as I adapted it.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @ben-albrecht answer, I just spent some time on debugging/adapting it (as I don't like any approach to better history logging), so I'd like to contribute back.

the variant: `PROMPT_COMMAND='x=$?; echo $x >> ~/exit-codes.log; (exit $x)'` has one problem: if you want to log whole command and not just exitcode, you cannot access `$BASH_COMMAND` as any command you enter in this variable, will overwrite, so you will lose the original command. And if you use `history 1` it will work, but if you enter 'empty' command say 3 times, the bash history will not be updated, `history 1` will return the same thing 3 times and your history log will contain duplicates.

the variant with trap has another issue, and that's leaking variables. Variables set in it will be accessible outside, which might break this functionality or others. Next issue is, that command is logged only after next command is invoked. Then there is gotcha: if you set this in `.bashrc` file, it needs to be the last line there, otherwise all remaining commands will be logged as if you'd invoke them. And even then, there will be some logged command you didn't want to see in logs, for example fzf helper functions in my case.

So I did it like this. In .bashrc I declared function, which is then called by trap --> no variable leaking.

```
function record_permanent_history() { ec=$?;echo -e "$(date +%FT%T.%3N)\t${ec}\t${1}\t${PWD}" >> ~/.bash_history_permanent; return $ec;  }
trap 'record_permanent_history "${BASH_COMMAND}" ' DEBUG
```

shown code generates following lines:

```
2023-12-06T20:11:37.541 0   return $ec  /home/me
```

Fields delimited by tabulator, and order of fields is intentional and solves some issues:

1. First column is timestamp to allow faster ordering if needed.
2. Second column is exit code,
3. third column is actual command.
4. fourth column is current directory (probably wasteful, but sometimes someone has nice command but it does not work because of current directory and it's harder to figure out why).

This order is needed because of fzf. fzf has some specifics with delimiters other than space, and space/other chars can be contained in command itself. With this alignment, we can have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUT="$(fzf -d "\t" --scheme=history --with-nth 3..-2 --preview="echo 'time={1}'; echo 'ret={2}';echo dir='{-1}';echo;echo command;echo {3..-2}" --preview-window=right:wrap --expect=alt-enter < ~/.bash_history_permanent)"

KEY=$(echo "$OUT" | head -n 1)
CMD=$(echo "$OUT" | tail -n 1 | sed "s/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t\(.*\)\t[^\t]*$/\1/")

if [[ -n "${KEY}" ]]; then
        case "${KEY}" in
                alt-enter) eval "${CMD}"  ;;
        esac
else
        echo ${CMD};
fi
```

which will print you all information nicely presented, with fuzzy search, enter prints selected command to stdout, alt-enter executes it.

limitations:

- until fields access it fzf is improved, you are (probably) out of luck and directory name and command cannot contain actual tabulator symbol. Should not be a problem.
- fzf authors somehow achieved typing the command instead of printing to stdout. I need yet to understand this code and 'steal' it.

problems:

- usage of trap command is suboptimal. It logs function internals(as shown), and other command namely from .bashrc, but suprisingly not individual command from custom scripts. Aliases are substituted in log, which is truly unwanted.

probably good enough as first increment. I need to rewrite the trap to PROMPT_COMMAND and detect duplicates using command ID, which is trivially doable with one exposed env variable. I will update this answer when I have better solution.

Comment: You'll want to prefer `printf` over `echo -e`. The latter will not cope correctly with arbitrary backslashes in the message.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for hint, I will work it in. I'm positive there will be more problems, but I wanted to share rather sooner than never. I expect I'll have to update this several times.

Comment: @tripleee quick update. I'm still debugging the solution waiting for more problems to come, but you've been correct, `echo -e` is wrong, as it will substitute stuff I don't want to substitute. But the printf isnt any better, actually is even worse when used for expand variable containing generic command. So in my code above, I'm using echo -e just so that \t will be substituted. The correct solution is to type actual tabulator into string literal and lose -e flag. This seems to behave much better for this usecase.

Comment: Just use `printf '%s' "${str//\\t/$'\t'}"`

Comment: Also, [avoid upper case for your private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: @tripleee thanks for you hints. I had to google a little to understand it, but it is very nice! Still learning :)

Answer (score -1):

The last exit code is stored in the `$?` variable.

But then you have to check it for each issued commands so that still needs some glue to achieve your goal I guess.

Comment: Yes, the glue is the part I was trying to figure out here. I have posted a solution based on feedback in the comments.