# In bash file how to pass the error message

Tags: bash, shell

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

usrFile="${1}"

while read -r usrCMD
do exec -e "${usrCMD}" || echo_fun "${usrCMD}"
done < "$usrFile"
```

echo_fun is a function that prints the message.

In the echo_fun, I want to pass the error message of command `exec -e "${usrCMD}"`

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the `-e` option to `exec`? Or is that the error message you're trying to catch?

Comment: Why are you using `exec`? That will end the loop because it replaces the shell process with the command it's executing. Did you mean to use `eval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `stdout` to a variable, as explained in [How to store standard error in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable)

Then pass that variable to `echo_fun`

```
while read -r usrCMD; do
    error=$(exec -e "$usrCMD" 2>&1 >/dev/null) || echo_fun "$usrCMD $error"
done < "$usrFile"
```

Comment: Putting `exec` inside `$( )` runs it in a subshell, which rather defeats the usual purpose of `exec`. (Although I'm not sure that usual purpose is what's actually intended here...)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I made the point that `exec` is probably not what he wants in a comment above.

Comment: Unless he wants to loop until one of the `exec`s succeeds, printing the errors from the non-succeeding ones.