# Command output doesn't save to variable in bash

Tags: bash, debian, io-redirection

I need save the output of `apt-cache show debconf-2.0` to a variable, but however I try, the variable remains blank. `debconf-2.0` is a virtual package and when running it in the terminal it returns:

```
N: Can't select versions from package 'debconf-2.0' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

I need to get the command output in a script to see if the package is virtual by `grep`-ing the output to see if it contains "is purely virtual".

I tried it the normal way:

```bash
cmd_output=$(apt-cache show debconf-2.0)
echo "$cmd_output"
```

But this outputs nothing. Then I tried to grab stderr output with `2>&1`:

```bash
cmd_output=$(apt-cache show debconf-2.0 2>&1)
echo "$cmd_output"
```

which still outputs nothing. Another command to know if the package is virtual will also help.

To confirm a non-virtual package would return something to the variable, I tried this with a normal package, and it outputted the info just fine.

```bash
cmd_output=$(apt-cache show nano 2>&1)
echo "$cmd_output"
```

which returns:

```
Package: nano
Version: 7.2-1
Installed-Size: 2804
Maintainer: Jordi Mallace
...
```

**Note that this is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962255/how-to-store-standard-error-in-a-variable). I already mentioned that I've added `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout before asking this question. After asking, I found out an additional `-q=0` parameter was needed.**

Comment: I googled `apt-cache no output` and found these: [Cannot grep apt-cache show output - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1281658/301745), [Why isn't apt-cache policy output piped? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/201869/117037). In the future, please start with your own research; see [ask] for that and more tips.

Comment: I didn't know this answer was specific to apt-cache, i thought it was about any command that has stderr, so I didn't think about searching `apt-cache no output`

Comment: Not a duplicate. OP tried the techniques listed there, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. With more experience, you'd know that either of your first two attempts should have output at least *something*. For `apt-cache` to output *nothing* is extremely weird IMHO. (BTW, I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
cmd_output=$(apt-cache -q=0 show debconf-2.0 2>&1)
echo "$cmd_output"
```

Output:

```
N: Can't select versions from package 'debconf-2.0' as it is purely virtual
N: No packages found
```

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617079/74329